# can i smiulate 2 transactions using .call in web3 or in anyother way?

Tags: web3js, mev

i want to be able to simulate 2 transactions using .call in web3.js.
To see if 1 tx affects the other. I cant find a way to do so. .call only works for 1 at a time and a custome node takes a lot of time. Is there a way to do that ? , thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not depend on `msg.sender` in the contracts you want to simulate then you can use [multicall](https://github.com/makerdao/multicall).

But to properly simulate them as separate transactions coming from a specific sender address you currently will have to run your own node. The fastest you can do is to use a fork of mainnet (here a simple [tutorial](https://www.quicknode.com/guides/web3-sdks/how-to-fork-ethereum-blockchain-with-ganache) with ganache, but hardhat also supports this).